# Slack API to get applications installed in a workspace

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is there a way to get a list of applications installed in a workspace on slack? The closest thing i would was web api Users.list which lists all users. From the users list i can get the BOT users and determine the applications. However, some apps install without creating a BOT user so those get left out in the Users.list approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the API method [`team.integrationLogs`](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.integrationLogs). It provides you with a list of all integrations, including Slack apps.

Comment: Thanks. This helps get my use case done. Though it is a log to parse through, would be nice if slack had a "get apps installed" api.